# Simple AudioKit implementation giving MGIsDeviceOneOfType

Tags: ios, audiokit

I have a very simple code to record from microphone and then show the frequency and amplitude graph, as per the example, but its throwing an error.
I am running the code on simulator.
Below is the snippet.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
        do{
            tracker = AKFrequencyTracker.init(mic, hopSize: 200, peakCount: 2000)
            let silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)
            AudioKit.output = silence
            try AudioKit.start()
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

The error it throws is :

```
2018-11-20 23:44:23.056935+0530 PianoLayout[1623:22349] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
```

at 
AudioKit.start() line.

If I run the same code inside viewDidAppear I get

```
AURemoteIO::IOThread (8): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0
```

Thanks